# Scope management - Stateful IO Monad?

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-java

I am playing with functional programming and in particular with Functional Java. I have implemented with success my version of the IO Monad and I am writing IO actions for my core. It is basically serializing objects to Xml files (the object type extends the custom XmlWritable interface).

Unfortunately, in order to do that, an instance of OutputStream AND one instance of XmlSerializer needs to be created. The scope of the OutputStream is wider than XmlSerializer's, which means that the only way I can see to be able to correctly handle both lifecycles within my IO monad is to carry both of them with me in a tuple, closing OutputStream after having written using XmlSerializer.

This leads to heavy and ugly code (Java 6 is definitely not the best for this):

```
public abstract class IO<R> {
    [...]
}

public class IOActions {

    public final F<String, IO<OutputStream>> openFileFn() {
        return new F<String, IO<OutputStream>>() {
            @Override
            public IO<OutputStream> f(String fileName) {
                [...]
            }
        };
    }

    /* This will be partially applied, encoding will be fixed */
    public static final F<OutputStream, IO<P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer>>> initSerializer() {
        return new F<OutputStream, IO<P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer>>>() {
            @Override
            public IO<P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer>> f(OutputStream os) {
                XmlSerializer = new ...
                [...]
            }

        };
    }

    /* This will be partially applied as well */
    public static final F2<XmlWritable, P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer>, IO<P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer>>> writeObjectFn() {
        return new F2<XmlWritable, P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer>, IO<P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer>>>() {
            @Override
            public IO<P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer>> f(XmlWritable object, P2<OutputStream, XmlSerializer> p) {
                [...]
            }
        };
    }
```

Is there a more idiomatic why to handle my use case in functional programming?

Lurking, I discovered the State Monad...but I am kind of scared to see what it is going to happen if I apply a State Monad on top of a IO Monad in Functional Java.

Comment: I'm slogging through reading your code right now (Sorry, Java 6 is painful for FP) but the IO **is** the state monad, in a more specialized form

Comment: Ok no problem :) Is it a common pattern to pass around tuples when you need to maintain some state across Monadic functions?

Comment: Allow me a question: why are you doing this stuff in a language that is not very well suited for it? You could use Scala, Clojure or Frege to write the functional parts of your program.

Comment: Your question is good indeed :) I have this constraint unfortunately. But I know Scala, so any Scala answer is accepted as well! Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the constraint? To use the "functional java library", or to produce java code?

Comment: Produce Java code and work in Java-only environment, but again, the question is more theory than code. It can be answered in very generic terms...btw I am lurking in the Haskell wiki to see if I can find my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I actually took great inspiration from Functional-Java's [DB combinators](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/tree/master/core/src/main/java/fj/control/db) to solve similar problems. I made my very own "XML combinators" (and more) from this pattern, so its worth learning.

You might find [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/functionaljava/AMcLld-78fI/KOoOzczRX4MJ) on google groups useful.

edit - replying to the comment:

follow the code: 
notice how you start a new connection using the [StateDb](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/control/db/DbState.java#L41), see that you have a few options to start a connection, one that eventually commits, and one that eventually rollback. these are just two examples of things you can "carry" with the computation. Essentially, every computation that you [bind](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/control/db/DB.java#L103) (a plain modaic bind), could potentially carry information.

here is an example i gave in the discussion above:

```
DB<PreparedStatement> prepareStatement(final String sql) {
  return new DB<PreparedStatement>() {
     public PreparedStatement run(Connection c) throws SQLException {
        return c.prepareStatement(sql);
}}}

// for a query that a reader might perform, i might have a function like this:   
F<PreparedStatement, DB<ResultSet>> runStatement() {
   public DB<ResultSet> f(final PreparedStatement s) {
      return new DB<ResultSet>() {
        public ResultSet run (Connection c) throws SQLException {
           return s.executeQuery();
}}}
```

So in this example, you can pass extra information, namely the sql query as a parameter to the function that gets bound. you could just as well had more parameters to runStatement.

to put it all together, you get something like:

```
ResultSet rs = DbState.reader("conn-url").run(prepareStatement("select * from table").bind(runStatement());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice, thanks! I am close too see how to handle this, but I still don't see it. Basically, following your page, how can I handle the fact that I need to carry Connection with me to the end of the computation so that I can close it?

Comment: I see now, the Connection is carried as part of the DBState object and closed inside DBState.run(), passing from one DB Monad to another in the DB<A>.run(final Connection c).
Well this is acceptable for this kind of application, but it is not very generic...for generic IO Monads I need to come up with another solution I guess, following the DBState implementation though. Maybe passing one (or more) Closable object. So...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have come up with. Feedback is very appreciated.
I followed the answer above, taking inspiration from the [linked](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/functionaljava/AMcLld-78fI/KOoOzczRX4MJ) discussion:

```
public class IOXml<T extends XmlWritable> implements DataWriter<T>{

    private final XmlSerializer mXmlSerializer;
    private final Option<String> mXmlEncoding;
    private final IO<OutputStream> ioCreateStream;
    private final F<OutputStream, IO<Unit>> ioCloseStream;

    @Inject
    IOXml(IO<OutputStream> createStream, F<OutputStream, IO<Unit>> closeStream, XmlSerializer xmlSerializer, Option<String> xmlEncoding) {
        mXmlSerializer = xmlSerializer;
        mXmlEncoding = xmlEncoding;
        ioCreateStream = createStream;
        ioCloseStream = closeStream;
    }

    /**
     * Write a T object which is XmlWritable.

     * @param osAndSer The tuple containing OutputStream and XmlSerializer.
     * @param object The object to write.
     * @return IO monad object.
     */
    protected IO<Unit> writeObject(final T object) {
        return new IO<Unit>() {
            @Override
            public Unit performIO() throws IOException {
                object.writeXml(mXmlSerializer);
                return Unit.unit();
            }
        };
    }

    protected final F<Unit, IO<Unit>> writeObjectFn(final T object) {
        return new F<Unit, IO<Unit>>() {
            @Override
            public IO<Unit> f(Unit a) {
                return writeObject(object);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the XmlSerializer before using it.
     * @param os An OutputStream.
     * @param encoding The encoding of the xml file.
     * @return An IO action returning nothing.
     */
    protected IO<Unit> initXml(final OutputStream os) {
        return new IO<Unit>() {
            @Override
            public Unit performIO() throws IOException {
                mXmlSerializer.setOutput(os, mXmlEncoding.toNull());
                mXmlSerializer.startDocument(mXmlEncoding.toNull(), true);
                return Unit.unit();
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Close the XmlSerializer after.
     * @return An IO action returning nothing.
     */
    protected IO<Unit> closeXml() {
        return new IO<Unit>() {
            @Override
            public Unit performIO() throws IOException {
                mXmlSerializer.endDocument();
                return Unit.unit();
            }
        };
    }

    protected final F<Unit, IO<Unit>> closeXmlFn() {
        return new F<Unit, IO<Unit>>() {
            @Override
            public IO<Unit> f(Unit a) {
                return closeXml();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        closeXml().performIO();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(T object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Are you sure? IOXml is a functional class. Use the function returned by liftIO instead.");
    }

    /**
     * Curried function to write XML objects, given the object itself and an OutputStream.
     * @return The curried function.
     */
    protected F<OutputStream, F<T, IO<Unit>>> writeFn() {
        // returning the outer
        return new F<OutputStream, F<T, IO<Unit>>>() {
            @Override
            public F<T, IO<Unit>> f(final OutputStream os) {
                // Returning the inner
                return new F<T, IO<Unit>>() {
                    @Override
                    public IO<Unit> f(T object) {
                        return initXml(os).bind(writeObjectFn(object)).bind(closeXmlFn());
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public IO<Unit> writeIO(final T object) {
        return IOImpl.bracket(ioCreateStream,                      // init
                       ioCloseStream,                              // close
                       Function.partialApply2(writeFn(), object)); // body

    }
}
```